# Setting authorization header from local storage race issue?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Apollo client suggest following code to set authentication header, where data from local storage is shown as synchronous function call.

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

In this line,

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
```

we mostly use async/await to get data from local storage, in that case authLink will be async function right? eg:

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
```

i believe that means,

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

this lines run before we fulfill async httpLink function call, is not this a race issue? will apollo assign httpLink to authLink.concat after promise is fulfilled ??